# What do Belken Devices say for "load cartridge"?

Tags: nanoha

I'm trying to figure out what Belken Devices like Graf Eisen and Laevatein say when they use the Cartridge System, i know that when Mid-Children Devices Rasing Heart and Bardiche say the English "Load Cartridge"

i have tried passing in "load cartridge" into Google Translate, ofcause that [didn't go well](https://translate.google.com/#en/de/load%20cartridge) and i also did [load](https://translate.google.com/#en/de/load) and [cartridge](https://translate.google.com/#en/de/cartridge) separately however can't find neither one in the Nanoha A's Special CD Soundtracks (which came with some tracks of the Devices talking).

i'm looking for what they say *and* the English equivalent on the off chance they don't say word-for-word load cartridge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quote from the manga wikia on Vita's list of attacks:

> Nachladen — Not a real attack, just Graf Eisen reloading cartridges.
>
> Explosion — Also not an attack; Graf Eisen says this when using cartridges, analogous to the English-speaking devices' "Load cartridge."

Source: [Vita (Nanoha) Manga Wikia page](http://manga.wikia.com/wiki/Vita_%28Nanoha%29)

Nachladen is also the term listed on the [Signum manga wikia page](http://manga.wikia.com/wiki/Signum_%28Nanoha%29), a German word which translates to "Reload".

Despite what the manga wikia says, I always thought that the Belken devices use "Reload" in the same way that the Mid-Children Devices use "Load Cartridge", and "Explosion" is when they're being used, particularly multiple cartridges. (Passing reference of this on the [Nanoha wikia Vita page](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Vita#Powers)).

I admit that I have not watch/read/listened to all of the anime, manga, drama CD, etc. and my understanding is that there may be minor differences.

Comment: in the Nanoha A's Special CD Soundtracks Laevatein also says explosion (it seems to be pronounced differently). i'd have to dig up the anime to see what happens when *"Explosion"* is said but since the copy i have had fan subs i kinda don't trust them for iding *"Nachladen"*. could you explain the difference between *"reloading cartridges"* and the *"analogous to the English-speaking devices' "Load cartridge.""* because to me it seems the same.

Comment: I am accepting now however as the Book of Darkness and Klarwind uses "Anfang" which equals "Start" instead of the Mid-Childan "Standby Ready, Setup" so "Nachladen" = "Reload" would make sense if Belkan Devices don't use the exact same phrasing as Mid-Childan ones but similar, less wordy versions

Comment: updated the answer a bit. Sorry I don't have a definitive answer. I'd have to dig up my copies and I'm not entirely sure where they are right now.